Firebase data sync
The Java Android app receives a FCM and write a value to Firebase.  Sometimes this value does not immediately appear in the Firebase console.  It always appears eventually.
Question: How can I ensure that database updates are synced immediately in this situation?

You can't force the database, its SDKs, or the console to work any faster than they already do.  But you can be certain that when the SDK says a write operation is complete, that data has been fully written to the database and will show up in the next query.
If you think there is a problem with the console, then reach out to Firebase support directly.  The volunteers of Stack Overflow can't help you with that.

No problem with console. The app used to work better.  It used upstream FCM messaging as a way to call back-end API.  XMPP was discontinued and upstream FCM messaging is no longer possible.  Old app: 1) Send downstream FCM to Android where a value is calculated 2) send an upstream FCM message containing the calculated value to the server where Java Admin SDK writes it to Firebase.  The old app worked every time.   The new app just writes the value to Firebase within the Android app.  This value doesn’t always show up in the cloud right away - but most of the time it works fine.

If you think there's a problem with Firebase services, you should reach out to Firebase support.  We can't help you with what you're describing, especially if you're not showing code and instructions in your question that can reproduce the issue.

Fair enough..  I was looking for something like "Use a Cloud Function For This".  Maybe someone knew that channel would work better for this case.  Or maybe it's a Proxy/Firewall issue somewhere along the line (the app is used internationally) that affects Firebase but not FCM.   Maybe I should make a HTTPS call from the client and have back-end code set the value instead of relying on Firebase.  Mostly it works as is..  Thanks!

If the Android is app is backgrounded the FCM handler may not be running until the app is next opened.

That doesn't seem to match the scenario.  The FCM is received.  It uses a full screen intent to open an Activity.  A button in the Activity writes a value to Firebase.  The value does not immediatly (within 10 minutes) sync with the cloud.  It always eventually syncs.  The app needs to see the value right away.  Most of the time it works fine.
